# CardView compatPadding issue

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-cardview

Ok, so my problem is I use NO compatPadding in my project. And everything is ok for Lollipop Android versions and higher - I have no compatPading there aka no space between cards. But for pre Lollipop I see that padding anyway. 
How to get rid of padding on pre Lollipop in CardView? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

On API 20 and before, CardView does not clip the bounds of the Card for the rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to content so that it won't overlap with the rounded corners.
So for pre-lollipop devices You have to call setPreventCornerOverlap (false); on the card view or card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean)

Comment: It didn't work. Result is the same >L - has no padding, <L - still has padding